# Using JQuery, how can I differentiate one click from the next on the same element?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am trying to implement a click on an HTML element with JQuery, but I am having issues figuring out how to make the system understand that two different clicks are needed.  I understand how to make it work with two different buttons, but I am having trouble understanding how to make it work by making one click on the element.

For example, when I click the `h3` the system runs both functions; it would slide up and then it would slide down right after.  I need to have 1 click on the `h3` and have the function run the `.slideUp()` and stop.  Once it's stopped, I would need to click on it again to run the `.slideDown()`.  This is for a class project, and I must use the following functions:

```
animate()
fadeIn()
fadeOut()
slideDown()
slideUp()
```

Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready( function(){
   $('h3').on('click', function(){
     $(this).next().slideUp('slow');
   });

   $('h3').on('click', function(){
     $(this).next().slideDown('slow');
   });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `slideToggle()`, remove the other listener:

```
$(document).ready( function(){
   $('h3').on('click', function(){
      $(this).next().slideToggle('slow');
   })
})
```

If you must use `slideUp` and `slideDown`, use a variable:

```
$(document).ready( function(){
   var shouldOpen = true;
   $('h3').on('click', function(){
      if(shouldOpen) $(this).next().slideDown('slow');
      else $(this).next().slideUp('slow');
      shouldOpen = !shouldOpen;
   })
})
```

Comment: I did use the ```slideToggle()``` on my previous task, however, this is for a class project and apparently I need to use the elements mentioned. :(

Comment: @AdrianAcostaPR Edited answer

Comment: Can this format/syntax be used for the other elements mentioned?

Answer (score 1):

You could use `slideToogle` to achieve that but, in general you can define a variable to keep tracking of which function to call next:

```js
$(document).ready( function(){
   let track = "up"
   $('h3').on('click', function(){
    if(track == "down") $(this).next().slideUp('slow');
    track = "up";
});

   $('h3').on('click', function(){
      if(track == "up") $(this).next().slideDown('slow');
      track = "down";
});
```